# Add or remove single pixels from selection in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selection, pixels, photoshop-cs6, emoticons

Sometimes in Photoshop I'm working with images at very close-up levels, 
such as small animated GIFs and emoticons. Often I'm zoomed in all the way, working at pixel level.

If I've got a selection loaded, but want to 'edit' it by adding - or removing - single pixels at a time, is there a way to do this?

It's a very simple thing I need to do: just click on individual pixels and somehow add/remove them from the current selection.

For example: in the image below, you can see the area I have selected, and I want to deselect the two blue pixels down the bottom left, from that particular selection.

[image: photoshop pixel-close selection example]

Does Photoshop actually allow such fine control over selection areas and shapes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it does. Just use the "Rectangular marquee tool", hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, click on any corner of the pixel you want to deselect, drag your mouse to the opposite corner and release.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't think that I'd need to drag from one corner to the other of the pixel in question, I was trying alt/ctrl/shift but was only clicking on the pixel in question!

And also as a helpful comment to anyone out there while we document this knowledge on the Internet: if you want to ever select a single pixel as a new selection, (with one-click ease), use any of the marquee tools, in its options at the top select style, choose fixed size, and 1x1. Add new additions to the selection with Shift +.

Thanks m4573r! Now I can go forth and work with as much pixel accuracy and control as I like!

Comment: @frenchglen see also http://superuser.com/questions/385833/photoshop-pixel-accuracy?rq=1